# Ionic InAppBrowser issue

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor, inappbrowser, ar.js

I have an Ionic App where I use AR.js and i have access to the camera. The web version works fine. I build an Android version with capacitor and I use **InAppBrowser** to access the site where i host the web app. But when i try to run the AR inside of the inappbrowser, I get an error of 'Permission denied' and it won't work. I've tried the plugin 'AndroidPermissions' as well as adding `<use-permission>` in the **AndroidManifest.xml** but still nothing. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your entire app is running in the InAppBrowser? If you're trying to use native feature through the InAppBrowser that won't work. Why not just host the app in the webview directly the way intended by the framework?

Comment: I've tried it (hosted the entire app in the webview) but it still gives me an error of permission denied. Today ive just tried creating an android studio project from scratch and including android webview in there that opens my url (my site) but now instead of permission denied i get nothing, literally. It doesnt even show the permission denied error. It's just a black screen. Like there is nothing to load. I tried debugging and i got this error :  ''E/chromium: [ERROR:web_contents_delegate.cc(227)] WebContentsDelegate::CheckMediaAccessPermission: Not supported.''

Comment: To give u a better view of things as simply as I can. I have an IonicVue project. In a component i have an iframe that has an html file as source and in that html file is where the AR is loaded and executed. I believe it has something to do with that but i cant tell. I tried hosting just the AR part online (as a site) in case there was a conflict with ionic or something but even alone the AR it gave me the error

Comment: I managed to get over the permission error but now i get an error saying 'could not start video device' or if i give permissions by hand in the settings i get a big play button that won't do anything by pressing it. At this point I think that there is some compatibility issues cause i get geolocation errors as well while i have granted location permissions and have location turned on